# How do i compare two files based on certain columns using unix shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix, awk

i have two files say file1 and file2 which has some similar and different data's in both.i want to extract the data that has different data based on column 1 and column2. the sample files would be like.

File 1:

```
COL1        COL2   COL3
fruits      apple    50
fruits      mango    60
fruits      kiwi     35
vegetable   tomato   20
vegetable   brinjal  30
```

File 2:

```
COL1        COL2   COL3
fruits      apple    50
fruits      orange   25
vegetable   tomato   20
vegetable   potato   25
sauce       chilly   78
```

output should be like :

```
COL1        COL2     COL3
fruits      mango    60
fruits      kiwi     35
vegetable   brinjal  30
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why not _fruits      orange_, _vegetable   potato_ and _sauce       chilly_? Please edit the original question with the explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want what is called *difference* in set arithmetics parlance. I would use GNU `AWK` for this task as follows, let `file1.txt` content be

```
fruits      apple    50
fruits      mango    60
fruits      kiwi     35
vegetable   tomato   20
vegetable   brinjal  30
```

and `file2.txt` content be

```
fruits      apple    50
fruits      orange   25
vegetable   tomato   20
vegetable   potato   25
sauce       chilly   78
```

then

```
awk '(FNR==NR){arr[$1,$2]=$0}(FNR!=NR){delete arr[$1,$2]}END{for(i in arr){print arr[i]}}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

output

```
fruits      kiwi     35
fruits      mango    60
vegetable   brinjal  30
```

Explanation: I use array `arr`, when going through first file (`FNR==NR`) I simply set `arr`'s value for key being concatenation of 1st and 2nd column to whole line (`$0`), in all but first file(s) (`FNR!=NR`) I do remove key made same way as earlier from `arr` using `delete`, note that there is nothing wrong with using `delete` with key which does not exist. When all files are processed I do `print` values from `arr` using `for` loop. This might be used with more than 2 files, in which case effect would be same as concating 2nd and next files together before feeding them. **DISCLAIMER** this solution assumes that you do not care about rows order in output

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: hi @Daweo i am getting 0 in results.can you help me with this?